# Removing spaces between items in list of Integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

how to make it

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

Split and replace wont work as it is an integer list.

Comment: Do you have a string or a list?

Comment: try `repr(a).replace(' ', '')`

Comment: Actually i am trying to print a pascal triangle properly. Just trying to ignore these spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are not part of your object which means that you can not remove them. That's just a representation choice. e.g.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4] 
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But if you want to print your list in string mode you can use `str.replace()`:

```
>>> str(a).replace(' ','')
'[1,2,3,4]'
```

Comment: I will try to make use of it :) Cheers !!

Comment: `TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: @BlackThunder Using `translate` isn't a good idea here and not necessary at all. The error also occurs because you have to create the table with `str.maketrans()` first and then pass the table to `str.translate`.